# can't style border when pressed on radio button in react

Tags: css, reactjs, radio-button

so i have create these divs and made them act like a radio button:

[![these 4divs][1]][1]

when i press on one of them i want the border to be colored blue like border: 2px solid blue;

but instead this is happening:

[![the problem][2]][2]

what can i do to make the border color in blue like this:

sudies.js code:

```
<ul>
            <li>
            <input type='radio' value= '1' name ='radio' id='radio1'/>
            <label for='radio1'><div className="rcorners2 " ></div></label>
            </li>
            <li>
        <input type='radio' value='2' name='radio'  id='radio2'/>
        <label for='radio2'><div className="rcorners2 " ></div></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' value='3' name='radio'  id='radio3'/>
        <label for='radio3'><div className="rcorners2 " ></div></label>
    </li>

        </ul>
```

sudies.css:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
input{
    visibility:hidden;
}
label{
    cursor:pointer;
}
input:checked + label {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of extra `div` you can style label to get desired output.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

input:checked+label {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type='radio' value='1' name='radio' id='radio1' />
    <label for='radio1'>Radio 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='radio' value='2' name='radio' id='radio2' />
    <label for='radio2'>Radio 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='radio' value='3' name='radio' id='radio3' />
    <label for='radio3'>Radio 3</label>
  </li>

</ul>
```